# Append Child to End of Specific Spot on XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to append data to the end of a specific place in the XML Below.

My XML is a lot longer, but for instance, I want to append Data to the end of the section labeled "Delete". I would then be adding different data to the end of "Total Tickets", but if I can somehow figure out how to append data to the end of the first child, I can figure out the rest.

```
<report>
<sets>
<set>
  <legend>Delete</legend>
  <values>
    <value date="2012-06-24" data="9"/>
    <value date="2012-06-25" data="17"/>
    <value date="2012-06-26" data="15"/>
    <value date="2012-06-27" data="10"/>
    <value date="2012-06-28" data="8"/>
  </values>
</set>
   <set>
  <legend>Total Tickets</legend>
  <values>
    <value date="2012-06-24" data="412"/>
    <value date="2012-06-25" data="416"/>
    <value date="2012-06-26" data="423"/>
    <value date="2012-06-27" data="405"/>
    <value date="2012-06-28" data="280"/>
  </values>
</set>
</sets>
</report>
```

Below is a test script I wrote to see the results. In this instance, I am trying to append the Element 'value' with Attribute data of '12345' at the end of the list of the legend "Delete"

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->load('result.xml');

$test = $doc->getElementsByTagName("legend")->item(0);

echo $test->nodeValue.PHP_EOL; //should print Delete

if("Delete" == $test->nodeValue)
{

    $newElement = $doc->createElement('value');
    $theAttribute = $doc->createAttribute('date');

    $theAttribute->value='12345';

    $newElement->appendChild($theAttribute);

    $doc->appendChild($newElement);

}


echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

The Results I get is this:

```
<report>
<sets>
<set>
  <legend>Delete</legend>
  <values>
    <value date="2012-06-24" data="9"/>
    <value date="2012-06-25" data="17"/>
    <value date="2012-06-26" data="15"/>
    <value date="2012-06-27" data="10"/>
    <value date="2012-06-28" data="8"/>
  </values>
</set>
   <set>
  <legend>Total Tickets</legend>
  <values>

    <value date="2012-06-24" data="412"/>
    <value date="2012-06-25" data="416"/>
    <value date="2012-06-26" data="423"/>
    <value date="2012-06-27" data="405"/>
    <value date="2012-06-28" data="280"/>
  </values>
</set>
</sets>
</report>
<value date="12345"/>
```

I'm trying to get the data shown as this instead:

```
<report>
<sets>
<set>
  <legend>Delete</legend>
  <values>
    <value date="2012-06-24" data="9"/>
    <value date="2012-06-25" data="17"/>
    <value date="2012-06-26" data="15"/>
    <value date="2012-06-27" data="10"/>
    <value date="2012-06-28" data="8"/>
    <value date="12345"/>
  </values>
</set>
```

Not sure how I can get the data to be added to that specific spot instead of the very end of the XML.

I appreciate anyones help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Original XML File (save it as 'testFile.xml'):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<report>
    <sets>
        <set>
            <legend>Delete</legend>
            <values>
                <value date="2012-06-24" data="9"/>
                <value date="2012-06-25" data="17"/>
                <value date="2012-06-26" data="15"/>
                <value date="2012-06-27" data="10"/>
                <value date="2012-06-28" data="8"/>
            </values>
        </set>
        <set>
            <legend>Total Tickets</legend>
            <values>
                <value date="2012-06-24" data="412"/>
                <value date="2012-06-25" data="416"/>
                <value date="2012-06-26" data="423"/>
                <value date="2012-06-27" data="405"/>
                <value date="2012-06-28" data="280"/>
            </values>
        </set>
    </sets>
</report>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument( '1.0' );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

// load the xml file
$dom->load( 'testFile.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// prepare the xpath query to find the "values" node corresponding the
// "Delete" legend
$nodes = $xpath->query("//set[legend='Delete']/values");

// if found, append the new "value" node
if( $nodes->length ) {
    $vNode = $dom->createElement( 'value' );
    $vNodeAttr = $dom->createAttribute( 'date' );
    $vNodeAttr->value = '12345';

    $vNode->appendChild($vNodeAttr);

    // append to "values"
    $nodes->item(0)->appendChild( $vNode );
}

// i'm not saving it, just echo'ing
header( 'content-type: text/xml' );
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

**Final XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<report>
  <sets>
    <set>
      <legend>Delete</legend>
      <values>
        <value date="2012-06-24" data="9"/>
        <value date="2012-06-25" data="17"/>
        <value date="2012-06-26" data="15"/>
        <value date="2012-06-27" data="10"/>
        <value date="2012-06-28" data="8"/>
        <!--Node appended here-->
        <value date="12345"/>
      </values>
    </set>
    <set>
      <legend>Total Tickets</legend>
      <values>
        <value date="2012-06-24" data="412"/>
        <value date="2012-06-25" data="416"/>
        <value date="2012-06-26" data="423"/>
        <value date="2012-06-27" data="405"/>
        <value date="2012-06-28" data="280"/>
      </values>
    </set>
  </sets>
</report>
```

Hope this helps.