# Add small XML files to a specific place in a big XML file PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a big XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catpharma date_generation="28-02-2019" version_xsd="6">
    <cat>
        <node1>xxx</node1>
        <node2>xxx</node2>
        <node3>xxx</node3>
        <date/>
        <!-- data from the small xml files need to be appended here --> 

        <node4>
        ...
```

Then I have several small XML files which need to be appended just after the `date` node.

The small XML files look like that:

```
<gamme>
    <id>1234</id>
    <nom>xxx</nom>
    <position>29</position>
    <gamme>
        <id>4567</id>
        <nom>zzz</nom>
        <position>2705</position>
    </gamme>
</gamme>
```

Through a loop I will know which correct "small" XML file need to be appended, that is, each time the loop is iterated, a "small" XML file is appended to the big one.

The final result needs to be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <catpharma date_generation="28-02-2019" version_xsd="6">
        <cat>
            <node1>xxx</node1>
            <node2>xxx</node2>
            <node3>xxx</node3>
            <date/>
            <gamme>
                <id>1234</id>
                <nom>xxx</nom>
                <position>29</position>
                <gamme>
                    <id>4567</id>
                    <nom>zzz</nom>
                    <position>2705</position>
                </gamme>
            </gamme>
            <!-- more `gamme` nodes from other small XML files to be added here-->
            <node4>
            ...
```

All the solutions I have seen thus far suggest that you create a node in the big XML file then continue to add the details of the sub-nodes one by one (for example this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499112/7524152)).

But the thing is since I will already have the "gamme" nodes in the small xml files, can't I read the file as a whole and just add it there?(without have to read the lines in the small xml files one by one).

So far I haven't seen any solutions to the way I want to implement it.

Comment: It's not ok to have `<gamme>` inside another `<gamme>` consider using `<gammes>` for the parrent. It's valid as an xml but not ok though.

Comment: I think you should put all `<gamme>` on the same level inside a `<gammes>` and use a `parent_id` for the nested ones.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa the thing is I have to absolutely work with the "small" files the way they are; that is, my job is to just put the data from the small files into the big one as it is. I cannot modify anything inside the "small" files unfortunately. The other system that will be receiving the final xml file doesn't know anything about `<gammes>`, so it will encounter errors on parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a node in the target document. Any valid XML document has a single document element node. So you will have to load the main document, find the specific node. Iterate the detail documents and import and append its document element.

For the following examples I put stripped down the XML and put it into string literals. to use files just change the loading method.

```
$mainXML = <<<'XML'
<catpharma>
    <cat>
        <node1/>
        <date/>
        <node4/>
    </cat>    
    <date/>
</catpharma>
XML;

$detailXMLs = [
  '<gamme><id>1234</id></gamme>',
  '<gamme><id>5678</id></gamme>',
];

// create document and load the main XML
$main = new DOMDocument();
$main->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$main->loadXML($mainXML);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($main);

// iterate the first "date" element in the document
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(//date)[1]') as $dateNode) {
    // iterate the detail XML strings
    foreach ($detailXMLs as $detailXML) {
        // load into a document
        $detail = new DOMDocument();
        $detail->loadXML($detailXML);

        // append into the parent of the "date" node
        $dateNode->parentNode->insertBefore(
            // import the document elment into the main document
            $main->importNode($detail->documentElement, TRUE),
            // insert before the node following the "date" node
            $dateNode->nextSibling
        );
    }
}

$main->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $main->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catpharma>
  <cat>
    <node1 />
    <date />
    <gamme>
      <id>5678</id>
    </gamme>
    <gamme>
      <id>1234</id>
    </gamme>
    <node4 />
  </cat>
  <date />
</catpharma>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the special purpose language designed to restructure XML files and can even import files its `document()` method. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) library. Plus, XSLT is portable can be run beyond PHP. Below assumes small XML files reside in same directory as larger XML file:

**XSLT** *(save as an .xsl file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
   <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- Identity Transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 

   <!-- Rewrite cat node -->
   <xsl:template match="cat">
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node1|node2|node3|date"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('small_file1.xml')/gamme"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('small_file2.xml')/gamme"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('small_file3.xml')/gamme"/>
        ...
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() &gt; 4]"/>             
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP**

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

Should you have many small XML files, have PHP run a loop to build the XSLT (which is actually a special XML file). Then, have PHP call the final script.